# Delay a for loop from completing until API call is returned

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-resource

Can anyone help with this problem... I'm on a page showing a record entered for the 22nd of March. I want to see if there is a record on the next day, and if theres not then I want to check the day after that for a record, and so on.

The problem I'm having is that the loop is completing before the API requests are being made. Heres an example of my code:

```
for (var d = date; d <= now; d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)) {   
  if (checkForRecord(d,now)) {
    break;
  } else if (!checkForRecord(d, now)) {
    // continue loop..
  }
}

function checkForRecord(date, now){
  var formatDate = moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  Record.query({_filter: {"date": formatDate}}, function(r){
    if (r.data.length > 0) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  });      
}
```

Is there anyway to delay a loop from completing until the API call is made?

Comment: You need asynchronous loop (or synchronous xhr, which will freeze you browser)

Comment: Or make use of promises http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/

Comment: Also (I read full question), I recommend you to not spam your API in that loop. Add an API method, which can to find solution by one call.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your function in a `promise` using `$q.when()` and resolve the rest of your code using `then()` when the function has finished executing. Remember to reference $q in your constructor.

```
for (var d = date; d <= now; d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)) {   
  var promise = $q.when(checkForRecord(date, now)); // creates a promise
  promise.then(function(result){ // resolve the promise using then()
    // succescallback
    if(result){
      break;
    }
  }, function(error){
    // errorcallback
    console.log(error);
  });
}

function checkForRecord(date, now){
  var formatDate = moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  Record.query({_filter: {"date": formatDate}}, function(r){
    if (r.data.length > 0) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  });      
}
```

Note that I have not actually implemented the above code, but it should provide you with an outline of how it can be solved.